# Modifying Instance Attribute Unexpected Behavior

Tags: python, data-structures, instance-variables, wordnet

I'm trying to implement a Graph/Node data structure to store some connections between synsets in WordNet.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

# a dict of [wn.synset, Node]
syns_node_dict = []

# gets a node from a wn.synset
def nodeFromSyn(syn):
    for row in syns_node_dict:
        if row[0] == syn:
            return row[1]
    return False    
def display_dict():
    for row in syns_node_dict:
        curr_nde = row[1]
        display([curr_nde._value, curr_nde._parents, curr_nde._children])
# Graph Node data struct
class Node:
    # value is a wn.synset
    # parents, children are both lists of wn.synset
    def __init__(self, value, parents=[], children=[]):
        curr = nodeFromSyn(value)
        # if a Node for value already exists, merge attributes
        if curr: 
            for p in parents:
                if p not in curr._parents : curr._parents.append(p)
            for c in children:
                if c not in curr._children : curr._children.append(c)
            self = curr
        # if a Node for value does not exist, create new Node for value
        else:
            syns_node_dict.append([value, self])
            self._value = value
            self._parents = parents
            self._children = children
        
        # Create a Node for each of self's parents if it does not already exist
        # and add self as a child
        for parent in self._parents:
            parent_node = nodeFromSyn(parent)
            if parent_node:
                if value not in parent_node._children:
                    parent_node._children.append(value)
            else:
                parent_node = Node(parent, children=[value])
                
        # Create a Node for each of self's children if it does not already exist
        # and add self as a parent
        for child in self._children:
            child_node = nodeFromSyn(child)
            if child_node:
                if value not in child_node._parents:
                    child_node._parents.append(value)
            else:
                child_node = Node(child, parents=[value])
```

However, I'm seeing some strange behavior when I attempt to run my code:

```
Node(wn.synset('condition.n.01'), [], children=[wn.synset('difficulty.n.03')])
display_dict()
>[Synset('condition.n.01'), [], [Synset('difficulty.n.03')]]
>[Synset('difficulty.n.03'), [Synset('condition.n.01')], []]

Node(wn.synset('state.n.02'), children=[wn.synset('condition.n.01')])
display_dict()
>[Synset('condition.n.01'), [Synset('state.n.02')], [Synset('difficulty.n.03')]]
>[Synset('difficulty.n.03'), [Synset('condition.n.01')], []]
>[Synset('state.n.02'), [], [Synset('condition.n.01')]]
```

When I run the following lines of code I expect the last line to be

> [Synset('attribute.n.02'), [], [Synset('state.n.02')]].

Why does the Node for `wn.synset('attribute.n.02')` contain itself among its parents?

```
Node(wn.synset('attribute.n.02'), children=[wn.synset('state.n.02')])
display_dict()
>[Synset('condition.n.01'), [Synset('state.n.02')], [Synset('difficulty.n.03')]]
>[Synset('difficulty.n.03'), [Synset('condition.n.01')], []]
>[Synset('state.n.02'), [Synset('attribute.n.02')], [Synset('condition.n.01')]]
>[Synset('attribute.n.02'), [Synset('attribute.n.02')], [Synset('state.n.02')]]
```

I isolated the issue to be within the block below but I can't figure out what's causing this behavior.

```
# Create a Node for each of self's children if it does not already exist
        # and add self as a parent
        for child in self._children:
            child_node = nodeFromSyn(child)
            if child_node:
                if value not in child_node._parents:
                    child_node._parents.append(value)
            else:
                child_node = Node(child, parents=[value])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Please mark my response as an answer if it answers your question. If not, leave a comment or edit your question to provide more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because default parameters are evaluated once when the function is *defined*, not each time it is *called*. Because of this, all the nodes you create with the `parents` (or `children`) parameter blank are actually sharing the same list for their parent list. For the first two nodes this isn't a problem because you specify an empty list for the first node, and the first node creates a list for the second, but all the nodes after that are sharing the same list (which becomes more obvious if you keep creating more nodes).

A way to solve this problem outlined [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) is to make the default parameters None, then check if the parameter is none and create the empty list if so:

```
# modify the init function so that the default parameters are None
def __init__(self, value, parents=None, children=None):
    # if they are left as None, set them to an empty list
    if parents is None:
        parents = []
    if children is None:
        children = []
    # The rest of your code here...
```